# How can i append multiple values to numPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I am making a snake game in pygame, and i need to make an array of pygame rects. When i was testing the code to see if the basic idea works, it didn't. When it was supposed to print

```
[[0,0],
[10,0],
[20,0],
```

and so on until it got to the biggest x value, and then it would add ten to the y value, it just prints the x values when the y value is always 0. I am new to pygame and python, so any help would be appreciated.
My code:

```
class Grid:

def __init__(self, gridSize):

    self.gridSize = gridSize
    self.numX = int(screenX / gridSize)
    self.numY = int(screenX / gridSize)
    self.xList = []

    for y in range(0, self.numY * 10, 10):

        for x in range(0, self.numX * 10, 10):

            self.xList.append((x,y))

        if y == 0:

            self.array = np.array(self.xList)

        else:

            np.append(self.array, self.xList)

        self.xList = []

    print(self.array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (if not all) `numpy` commands don't modify their arrays in-place. They *return* a new array, but the old array stays as it is.

Thus, under your `else`, you'll need

```
else:
   self.array = np.append(self.array, self.xList)
```

This will update `self.array` so that it holds the new, appended array.

It also explains why you're only seeing print-outs for `y = 0` and not other values. (You could possibly arrive at this same conclusion by debugging and stepping through your code. Maybe next time? :-) )

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you aren't iterating over the Y range:
`self.numY = int(screenX / gridSize)` needs to be `self.numY = int(`**screenY**`/ gridSize)`